# 403 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden) error in static files

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx

Please I have been stocked for days now trying to clear the error in my browser console (403 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)) and my static files is not been severed. Nginx Ubuntu

Comment: open up nginx.conf file and make sure you update USER which will be the first line . i was using aws ubuntu so i had to change it to `user ubuntu`

Comment: I don't really understand what you meant. How I'm I going to update USER. New to Ubuntu server

Answer (score 1):

go to this directory [image] Open nginx.conf
then change this [image] user to value as shown in this picture[image]
I had this issue got it fixed by this. maybe it helps. `user ubuntu`

Answer (score 0):

cd **/var/www/html**/ then **ls -la** to see permission
total 12
*drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 22 23:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Sep 22 23:14 ..*
**-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  612 Sep 22 23:14 index.nginx-debian.html**
I noticed that .html has no -x permission I gave it a permission with this commands
*find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;*
*find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;*
then *la -la*
total 12
**drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep 22 23:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Sep 22 23:14 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 22 23:14 html**
now html has -x permission
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
sudo systemctl restart nginx. This help fixed my problem and also big Thanks to hemal-patel changed my user too