# Next.js project responds correctly only when VPN is used

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js, http-status-code-403

This is my frontend (Next js) logs when I try to access the website **without **VPN:

```
example.com/:1     GET http://example.com:81/_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js?ts=1688363965400 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
example.com/:1     GET http://example.com:81/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1688363965400 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
example.com/:1     GET http://example.com/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1688363965400 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
example.com/:1     GET http://example.com/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1688363965400 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
example.com/:1     GET http://example.com/_next/static/chunks/pages/index.js?ts=1688363965400 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
```

I get ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden).

But it's OK when I use VPN!! (I live in Iran so there are many restrictions for my ip).

**But!** Many of my project files and folders are fetched correctly:
[image: Project files fetched by Google chrome]

What happens here?
Does it relate to the fact that I'm not currently using HTTPS?

- I should mention that I've tried these solutions ([403 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden) error in static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73781037/403-neterr-aborted-403-forbidden-error-in-static-files)) but it didn't help. So the problem is not because of the permissions of files.

At first, I thought this was because of my bad configuration of docker and Next js, but if they were incorrect, the website shouldn't be shown using a VPN.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... directly in the question body as code blocks**. (Pro tip: the `tree` command under linux gives you a text ouput of a directory structure you can paste directly in a code block) Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Thanks

Comment: Moreover, you obfuscated the fqdn of the server which is returning the 403 error. If this is not resolving to your local machine and your internet provider/country is restricting access to that IP, chances are the VPN will be mandatory in that case.

Comment: @Zeitounator No, that server is the same as my website's domain. They are hosted on the same machine, using dockerized next.js. So I'm not using fqdn.

Comment: example.com is a real domain and does not resolve to anything local to your machine.

Comment: @Zeitounator I know, I did it on purpose because I don't want to publish the domain and IP of my server :))

Comment: If you have an IP, why don't you put an IP? Would be easier to understand. No one can guess if you added that example domain on purpose or if you are really using it.

Comment: @Zeitounator Actually, I am using a real domain name. Can you tell me what practice is the best?